# How to add round values in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to individually add values together, while simultaneously rounding the values. Suppose, after rounding 12.5 will be 13 and 18.75 will be 19. I want to add 13+18.75. The result should be 32. How can I do this in VBA? [image]

Here is my code:

```
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("I6:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDif(C6, Today(),""m"")/12"
Range("H6:H" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDif(E6, Today(),""d"")/30+4"
Range("J6:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=I6+H6"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you

> want to add individually round values together

then you want this formula

```
Range("J6:J" & lastRow).Formula = "=ROUND(H6,0)+ROUND(I6,0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
Range("J6:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=CEILING.MATH((I6+H6),1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you´re just writing formulas into your dokument I would suggest you this solution:

```
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Range("I6:I" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDif(C6, Today(),""m"")/12"
Range("H6:H" & LastRow).Formula = "=DateDif(E6, Today(),""d"")/30+4"
Range("J6:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=Round(I6, 0) + Round(H6, 0)"
```

I just added the `Round` Formula with the parameters [value] and [number of digits]

Note that 1.5 + 1.5 would be 4 since both values are rounded befor adding.

Hope I could help.